# Getting 2 divs that both render partials side by side

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I can't get 2 divs that both contain rendered partials to sit side by side within a form. If I **replace the divs with normal text** they respond to my style change, but if I put the render code in, then they don't budge:

```
<div class="form">

      <%= form_for(@newevent) do |f| %>

          ...

          <div>
            <h2>Who's involved?</h2>

            <div class = 'sidebyside'>
                <div id = "left-calendar-wrapper">
                   <%= render partial: '/calendars/show', locals: {} %>
                </div>

                <div id ="right-calendar-wrapper">
                     this gets filled in by a javascript render in a js.erb file
                </div>
            </div>


          </div>

...
</div>
```

this is the CSS I have at the moment:

```
.sidebyside {
  float: left;
}

#left-calendar-wrapper {
  float: left;

}
```

Is it possible to do this with rendered partials? I would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The simple and clean solution:

You can use the **bootstrap** library to format your html. You will basically have this code

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-6' id='left-calendar-wrapper'></div>
  <div class='col-md-6' id='right-calendar-wrapper'></div>
</div>
```

You can get in depth documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code already:

```
<div class = sidebyside>
```

should be

```
<div class="sidebyside">
```

Maybe that's already the solution to your problem. If not, let me know.